# Display current value in the Classic Circular Linear Gauge using dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dojo

Is that possible to display the current value in the [classic circular linear gauge](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.3/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox/dgauges/tests/test_Classic_CircularLinearGauge.html) like in the [default circular linear gauge](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.3/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox/dgauges/tests/test_Default_CircularLinearGauge.html) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the script tag inside the test_Classic_CircularLinearGauge.html from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/_base/kernel","dojo/parser","dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "dojox/dgauges/components/classic/CircularLinearGauge"]);
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/_base/kernel","dojo/parser","dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
            "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
            "dojox/dgauges/components/classic/CircularLinearGauge"]);

    // ADD THE CURRENT VALUE TO INDICATOR
    require(["dojo/ready","dijit","dojox/dgauges/TextIndicator"],function(
            ready,dijit,TextIndicator){
        ready(function(){
            var gauge=dijit.registry.byId("g1"); // ADAPT THIS TO YOUR GAUGE ID
            indicator=gauge._elementsIndex.scale._indicators[0];
            var indicatorText=new TextIndicator();
            indicatorText.set("indicator",indicator);
            indicatorText.set("x",80);
            indicatorText.set("y",150);
            gauge.addElement("indicatorText",indicatorText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's kind of dirty, tough. A better way would be to create your own class out of the CircularLinearGauge and add the TextIndicator inside the constructor...

Comment: Is that possible to add a precision to the indicator ? like the **textIndicatorPrecision** attribute in the old version.

Comment: example ? it should be possible, just add it to the textindicator before you add it to the gauge

Comment: something like 15.33 => The precision is 2.

Comment: try setting the interval of your gauge... then the indicator should adapt.

Comment: this is a new question, create a new post please and i ll look into it.

Comment: This is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791408/textindicatorprecision-in-dojox-dgauges-using-dojo).